# How to convert from Linux commands to Python script?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.x

I want to run these 2 Linux commands (netcat and cat) from a Python scrypt. 
When I ran 2 Linux commands on the terminal, I got the content of file.txt
There was no output when I ran the Python script.

Here is my Python code. I think subprocess.Popen doesn't give me access to the server.

```
cmd1 = 'nc ' + '12.123.123.123' + ' 20'

cmd2 = 'cat file.txt'

process1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

process2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = process2.communicate()

print str(out)
```

Comment: When you run 'nc 2.123.123.123  20'  from shell, how does it behave? Does it expect you to type anything?

Comment: @Nipun Talukdar That specific IP address is just an example. When I run nc on terminal, the server responds with a few sentences. When I run that Python code, nothing happens :(

Comment: The server responds with a few sentences, and then do you need to press CTRL-C or something to exit from nc command?

Comment: Yes. How do I get the same behavior when running the Python script?

Comment: Well, do you *want* interactive input/output? Using `cmd1 = r'printf "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | nc www.stackoverflow.com 80'`, I get SO's home page.

Comment: – I see now it's not the home page ("forbidden") – but it works anyway.

Comment: It works to display the page. I actually need interactive input/output. Do you know how I can do it?

Comment: Check my answer below.

Comment: Using pure Python for this would give you a lot more control, and actually probably simplify your code. Python is perfectly capable of opening a network connection and copying bytes from one stream to another.

Answer (score 1):

As the command cmd1 needs CTRL-C to terminate it, hence process1 is not returning at all. So, we need to send CTRL-C to the subprocess. You should try one of the 2 ways as shown below:

```
import subprocess
import os
import signal
import time

cmd1 = 'nc 127.0.0.1 20'

process1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)  # No Shell......................
time.sleep(2)
process1.kill()
out, err = process1.communicate()
print out, err
```

Or something like below:

```
import subprocess
import os
import signal
import time

cmd1 = 'exec nc 127.0.0.1 20'   #NOTICE the exec here

process1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)  # No Shell......................
time.sleep(2)
print process1.pid
os.kill(process1.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
out, err = process1.communicate()
print out, err
```

Comment: In stead of doing os.kill(process1.pid, signal.SIGKILL),  you may just do process1.kill(), which will make it platform independent.